# linux shell script exec(wget) in java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I make server monitering application in java.

I exec shell script(wget --no-cache -t 1 -T 1000 --spider ServerURL 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP')

I gain result

but in java exec shell script..

I don`t gain result...

source code

```
String command = "wget --no-cache -t 1 -T 1000 --spider " + monitering_url +" 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP'";
shellCmd(command);
public static void shellCmd(String command) throws Exception {
          Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
          Process process = runtime.exec(command);
                    //Thread.sleep(5000);
          InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
          String line;
          while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(line);
          }
      }
```

monitering_url = serverURL

I want result print...

help me!!

Comment: That will need interpretation by a shell (for the pipe and redirection). Either invoke a script containing the commands or pass them to the interpreter.

Comment: I resolved problem thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your *command* is a shell script, and must be passed to a shell for interpretation:

```
Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", command});
```

Note the use of the array to pass the arguments to the shell process. Without it the command string will be tokenised before being passed to the interpreter, which is not what you want.